# How to get the location from where the google spreadsheet form is submitted

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Is there any way in google apps script to retrieve the location of user from where the user submits the google spreadsheet form ?

I am trying to create one form for new user subscription and want to get the location from where it gets submitted.

Please advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is possible that this [url](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geolocation) can help you (don't work in IE)

Comment: Try with soap  look at [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/soap_geoip_example?hl=en) I believe this does what you want. As far as I know the google maps api is not available in google Apps Script and the IP geolocation is not available in the maps class.